# Laravel Eloquent: multiple where() in the same column not working

Tags: laravel

In my Database, I have column 'publish' which values are 'new', 'pending', 'running' and 'paused'.
I want to make a query for 'pending' and 'running' at the same time. I use this Code but it's not working.

```
$q_editpost = Menu::select('id', 'bcrumb', 'heading', 'content_id', 'content_type')
        ->where('publish', 'pending')
        ->where('publish', 'running')
        ->get();
```

I need help!

Answer (score 16):

Two options, but the whereIn should be faster.

1)

```
$q_editpost = Menu::select('id', 'bcrumb', 'heading', 'content_id', 'content_type')
        ->whereIn('publish', ['pending', 'running'])
        ->get();
```

2)

```
$q_editpost = Menu::select('id', 'bcrumb', 'heading', 'content_id', 'content_type')
        ->where('publish', 'pending')
        ->orWhere('publish', 'running')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use whereIn for many where clouse.

```
$q_editpost = Menu::select('id', 'bcrumb', 'heading', 'content_id', 'content_type')
        ->whereIn('publish', ['pending', 'running'])
        ->get();
```